# Error in Flex webapp with TabNavigator loaded using SWFLoader - WebKit browsers

Tags: apache-flex, webkit, flexbuilder, swfloader, tabnavigator

I use a flex app (A) to load another flex app (B) using SWFLoader (both built using Flex Builder 3 sometime ago).

Everything works fine as expected across all (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari) desktop browsers.

However, if I use a TabNavigator within the flex app (B) then when you click on any of the tabs it unloads the flex app (B) and re-starts flex app (A). This behaviour appears to be limited to Webkit based browsers (Chrome & Safari) the rest of the browsers (IE, FF) work fine.

I wonder if anyone can throw some light on this.

Many thanks

Kind regards,
klem

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, or what question you're asking.

Comment: Apologies, if it seems confusing! let me try again..

Comment: I have a learning application (Flex App A) that loads learning resources (Flex App B) using SWFLoader. If however the learning resource (Flex App B) contains TabNavigator component then it does not seem to work in Webkit browsers (Safari & Chrome), i.e it unloads the learning resource (Flex app B) and re-starts the learning application (Flex app A). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand better; but don't have a solution.  Can you post code?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

Replacing the HTML template files with the latest copy from Flash Builder 4.5 seemed to resolve the issue. It appears they have replaced the AC_OETags.js with swfobject.js

Thanks in part to Harui for the nudge in the right direction.

Tried to explore upgrading the code to 4.5 but seemed to throw a lot of incompatibilities, created a test/dummy project instead in 4.5 and used the html file created to replace the old html files created by Flex Builder 3.0

Clearly not a very common problem, but hope this saves someone time, effort & aggro.